# Controlar si cambia o no el value de un input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esto y me funciona, me salta la alerta

```
        $("#TextField").change(function(){
            alert("El campo ha cambiado");
        });
```

Pero ahora intento hacer que salte la alerta dependiendo del value si cambia o no

He probado con esto y nada

```
        var item = document.getElementById("Picker").value

        item.change(function(){
            alert("El campo ha cambiado");
        });
```

También esto otro y nada

```
        $("[id*=Picker]").val.change(function(){
            alert("El campo ha cambiado");
        });
```

El campo es este

```
<INPUT name="Picker" id="Picker" type="hidden" value="AQUI">
```

Comment: puedes guardar el valor anterior en una variable y compararlos

Answer (score 4):

Para ver si ha cambiado el valor debes recoger dicho valor antes y compararlo con el valor cuando cambia el campo. No se puede aplicar la función `change` al valor del campo.

**Editado:** añadido ejemplo para campo oculto.

Es necesario lanzar el evento de cambio al cambiar el valor del campo, ya que cuando se cambia por programación el evento change no salta.

[Enlace original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17695465/5675636)

```js
var inival = $("#texto").val();
$("#texto").change(function(){
  if ( $("#texto").val() != inival ) {
   alert("El campo ha cambiado");
  }
});

//campo oculto
var inivalh = $("#textoh").val();
$("#textoh").val("cambiado").triggerHandler('change'); //cambiando el valor
$("#textoh").on("change", function(){ 
    alert('campo oculto cambiado');
}).triggerHandler('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="texto" name="texto" value="inicio"/>

<input type="hidden" id="textoh" name="textoh" value="inicio"/>
```

Comment: nada, lo mismo..

Comment: Acabo de ver que el input es tipo hidden, en ese caso no va a funcionar porque el evento change no salta cuando el valor del campo se cambia por programación, te paso un enlace donde indican como hacerlo en este caso https://stackoverflow.com/a/17695465/5675636

Comment: @PaoloFrigenti he añadido un ejemplo para campo oculto

Answer (score 2):

La forma mas sencilla para lograr lo que quieres es utilizar `bind()` veamos en el ejemplo como detectar el cambo:

Escuchamos los eventos **keyup, keydown y change.**

```js
$("#main").bind("keyup keydown change", function(){

  $("h5").html("El valor ha cambiado a: "+$("#main").val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="main" type="text" value="Default">

<h5>El valor ha cambiado a: Default</h5>
```

> **Revisión:**

Si quieres hacerle saber al usuario que no ha cambiado nada, podrías utilizar `focus()` y adentro `setTimeout()` para que si el usuario no cambia nada estando en el input salga un mensaje de alerta al pasar el tiempo especificado, algo como:

```js
$("#main").bind("keyup keydown change", function(){

  $("h5").html("El valor ha cambiado a: "+$("#main").val());
  
  // Cambio las clase defaulr a changed
  $("#main").addClass("changed");
  $("#main").removeClass("default")
  $("#temporal").remove(); //Me aseguro de eliminar el mensaje si algo cambia.

});

$("#main").focus(function(){

  $("body").append("<h5 id='temporal'>No has hecho ningun cambio.</h5>")
  $("#temporal").css({"visivility": "hidden", "opacity": "0"});
  
  // Solo ejecuto si el field aun contiene la clase default

  if ($("#main").hasClass("default")){
  
    setTimeout(function(){
  
    $("#temporal").css({"visivility": "visible", "opacity": "1"})
  
  },2000);
  setTimeout(function(){
  
    $("#temporal").remove();
  
  },4000);
  
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- introduzco una calse default para controlar si se ha cambiado o no -->
<input class="default" id="main" type="text" value="Default">

<h5>El valor ha cambiado a: Default</h5>
```

Comment: agradezco tu ayuda pero no es la funcion que busco, simplemente un alert cuando el valor del input cambia. el type del input es hidden

Comment: Podrías intentar usar el método [mutationObserver()](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-tracking-changes-in-the-dom-using-mutationobserver-86adc7446401) Para detectar cualquier cambio en el DOM con tus elementos. Disculpa que no me haya dado cuenta de que el input era type hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Los cambios en el valor de los elementos ocultos no desencadenan automáticamente el evento `.change()`. Entonces, donde quiera que establezca ese valor, también debe decirle a `jQuery` que lo active.

```js
$("#Boton").click(function() {
  $("#Picker").val("2").trigger('change');
});
$("#Picker").change(function() {
  alert("El campo ha cambiado");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Picker" type="hidden" value="1">
<input id="Boton" type="button" value="Cambiar">
```

> Aquí esta la respuesta en ingles:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533087/jquery-detect-value-change-on-hidden-input-field

Answer (score 0):

la respuesta más simple actualmente es:

html:

```
<select id="selectd">    
    <option value="v1"> v1 </option>
    <option value="v2"> v2 </option>
</select>
```

js:

```
<script>
var select = document.getElementById('selectd')

select.addEventListener('input', e =>{
    alert("El valor ha cambiado")
})

</script>
```

El evento "input" ocurre cuando el value de un elemento cambia o el contenido de un elemento con el atributo contenteditable se modifica.

en tu caso sería:

```
<script>

var item = document.getElementById("Picker")

item.addEventListener('input', e=>{
    alert("se ha producido un cambio")
})

</script>
```